# Counting the values of rows in a column and using the total value in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know this is something simple. I'm just forgetting something.

I'm counting the values of the rows in the "numberattending" column of my database. 
When I run the SQL statement

```
SELECT COUNT(numberattending) AS Total FROM RSVP
```

in the mySQL window I get the total I'm looking for.

When I try to extract that value and echo "num_seats" I get "Resource id #3"

```
$num_seats = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(numberattending) AS Total FROM RSVP", $connection);

echo $num_seats;
```

What I'm I missing?

Thanks for any help ahead of time.

Comment: a heads up, mysql is deprecated. use mysqli instead => http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$num_seats` represents a MySQL Resource, not the value of the field selected. You'll need to use either [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) or [`mysql_fetch_object()`](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php&ei=U-taUcLeJOjJ0AWdmICQAw&usg=AFQjCNE5tUE_riH_Y0ZPms6ex3BGd-ISyQ&sig2=t27q3N4Js0N4zvjacUW3fA&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k) depending on which you prefer.

For example:

```
$number = mysql_fetch_array($num_seats);
echo $number['Total'];
```

It's also worth noting that the `mysql_*` family of functions are now deprecated, and you should really be using [MySQLi](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php&ei=a-taUY36LOLW0QW-noCQAw&usg=AFQjCNEqr4MIMr-la3jWWjZ1PQbJFnyFHw&sig2=JnWNe29noXLYeQCXhCbWrQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k) or [PDO](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php&ei=X-taUc3LCcOk0QWszoHoDw&usg=AFQjCNFIwSE1mNG_k_lj0510AL_SsZs5Vg&sig2=SmyaCVJw1I23avjB2JH5VQ&bvm=bv.44442042,d.d2k).

Comment: This did it. Thanks. I should have remembered that I would have to use an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the result sets:

From the PHP site:

> // Use result // Attempting to print $result won't allow access to
>   information in the resource // One of the mysql result functions must
>   be used // See also mysql_result(), mysql_fetch_array(),
>   mysql_fetch_row(), etc.

```
$num_seats = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(numberattending) AS Total FROM RSVP", $connection);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($num_seats )) {
    echo $row['total'];

}
```

PS: As others will surely tell you, use of the `mysql*` functions have been deprecated. Look for the `mysqli` functions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(numberattending) AS Total FROM RSVP", $connection);

    $result = mysql_fetch_row($query);

    echo $result['Total'];
```